# Why does Capybara throw an error when the page works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara

I have a very simple capybara script for a custom sign-up form using devise:

```
  scenario "allow me to register and should take me to the new partner page" do
    visit '/registrations/become_partner'
    response.should be_success
  end
```

When I try to run the test, I get the following error:

```
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `first_name' for #<User:0x00000004d259e8>
```

even though this method is defined. I have the `attr_accesible` set in my model, the page renders, and I can call this method from the rails console. Why is capybara throwing this error when it is not a problem elsewhere?

Comment: Have you run `rake db:test:prepare` before running the specs?

Comment: no I did not.That did fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your test environment doesn't know that attribute yet - so apparently you have added the field `first_name` in your development environment, but not yet in your test environment.

To update your test environment, just run

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

and it will work. You should always do this after running a migration, it is a common error to run into.